# Code not working, Though it worked before

Tags: android, gettext, tostring, textedit

I was wondering if anyone could help me here. I am creating an Android application as my final project and it's running fine currently except for one part. The problem I have is that this class is not working

```
public class convert extends Activity
{
Button   mButton;
EditText eweight;
EditText eheight;
TextView t;
String s,s2;
double meters = 0;
double kg = 0;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
   getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.    FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
setContentView(R.layout.convert);
eweight   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.eweight);
eheight   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.eheight);
}
public void converth(View view) 
{

    s2 = convert.this.eweight.getText().toString();
    int stone = Integer.parseInt(s2);
    kg = stone*6.35;
    t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.newweight);
    t.setText(""+kg);
}
public void convertw(View view) 
{
    s  = convert.this.eheight.getText().toString();
    int feet = Integer.parseInt(s);
    meters = feet*0.3048;
    t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.newheight);
    t.setText(""+meters);
}   
public void pass(View view) 
{
    Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClassName("com.b00348312.workout","com.b00348312.workout.WorkoutChoice");
    if (meters > 0)
    {
        double number = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("height", meters);
    }
    if (kg > 0)
    {
        double number2 = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("weight", kg);
    }
    startActivity(i); 
}
```

When the buttons that set set up in the XML are pressed it pulls up a screen saying to force close the application.

The buttons are setup using the built in "andoid:onClick= ''" statement in the xml. The statements for the getText() are also used in this class and works fine

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
    // add a click listener to the button
    mPickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
        }
    });
    // get the current date
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // display the current date (this method is below)
    updateDisplay();

    mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.get);
    weight   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.weight);
    height   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.height);
    t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.out);

    mButton.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
               s = WorkoutChoice.this.weight.getText().toString();
               s2 = WorkoutChoice.this.height.getText().toString();
               int w = Integer.parseInt(s);
               double h = Double.parseDouble(s2);
               double BMI = (w/h)/h;
               t.setText(""+BMI);
            }
        });

}
```

Does anybody have any idea why the statement seems to work in one class and not the other:

Here is the thing from logcat:

```
03-05 22:22:34.637: E/global(2987): Deprecated Thread methods are not supported.
03-05 22:22:34.637: E/global(2987): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
03-05 22:22:34.637: E/global(2987):     at java.lang.VMThread.stop(VMThread.java:85)
03-05 22:22:34.637: E/global(2987):     at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:1391)
03-05 22:22:34.637: E/global(2987):     at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:1356)
03-05 22:22:34.637: E/global(2987):     at com.b00348312.workout.Splashscreen$1.run(Splashscreen.java:42)
03-05 22:22:54.597: D/dalvikvm(2987): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 6061 objects / 319632 bytes in 63ms
03-05 22:22:54.607: D/AndroidRuntime(2987): Shutting down VM
03-05 22:22:54.607: W/dalvikvm(2987): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400259f8)
03-05 22:22:54.627: E/AndroidRuntime(2987): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-05 22:22:54.627: E/AndroidRuntime(2987): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
03-05 22:22:54.627: E/AndroidRuntime(2987):     at   android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2072)
03-05 22:22:54.627: E/AndroidRuntime(2987):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
03-05 22:22:54.627: E/AndroidRuntime(2987):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8817)
03-05 22:22:54.627: E/AndroidRuntime(2987):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-05 22:22:54.627: E/AndroidRuntime(2987):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-05 22:22:54.627: E/AndroidRuntime(2987):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
03-05 22:22:54.627: E/AndroidRuntime(2987):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
03-05 22:22:54.627: E/AndroidRuntime(2987):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-05 22:22:54.627: E/AndroidRuntime(2987):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-05 22:22:54.627: E/AndroidRuntime(2987):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
03-05 22:22:54.627: E/AndroidRuntime(2987):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
03-05 22:22:54.627: E/AndroidRuntime(2987):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-05 22:22:54.627: E/AndroidRuntime(2987): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-05 22:22:54.627: E/AndroidRuntime(2987):     at com.b00348312.workout.convert.convertw(convert.java:44)
03-05 22:22:54.627: E/AndroidRuntime(2987):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-05 22:22:54.627: E/AndroidRuntime(2987):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-05 22:22:54.627: E/AndroidRuntime(2987):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2067)
03-05 22:22:54.627: E/AndroidRuntime(2987):     ... 11 more
03-05 22:22:54.627: E/AndroidRuntime(2987): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer
03-05 22:22:54.627: E/AndroidRuntime(2987):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:412)
03-05 22:22:54.627: E/AndroidRuntime(2987):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:382)
03-05 22:22:54.627: E/AndroidRuntime(2987):     ... 15 more
```

Comment: Post the stacktrace with the `Exception` you get in the `Logcat`?

Comment: can you post the fuill stacktrace on the logcat?

Comment: How do i get the stacktrace. i'm kinda new to this

Comment: Assuming you are using Eclipse, Window->Show View->LogCat. When you run your app while it's connected to your PC (i.e. adb is connected) and the error occurs, the stack trace will appear in the LogCat window. Paste it here so that people can help.

Comment: @JuuDaimeDazza Its important for you to learn a bit of java. This question is very basic in nature. For example, converth has parseInt '' which is a very clear exception. You need to check for empty fields before processing it. Its called input validation.

Comment: Thank for for helping and i do admit that i'm not well versed in java as i should be as before doing this the last time i coded was 2 years prior. but if the parseInt is an exception then what method should i use to get the value out of the text feild.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your later activity code... The problem is where you are doing findViewById() to find your buttons despite the fact you haven't set any layout for that particular activity.

Comment: the problem lies in the first activity. the second one works fine and displays what it needs to and does the calculation i need.

Answer (score -1):

Try doing a Project->Clean and rebuild. If it worked before and you haven't edited it since the last successful run, a clean should help.

Comment: the line "s2 = convert.this.eweight.getText().toString();" works fine in the second class. and i need it to do the same thing in the first class but it doesnt seem to work. i think it might have some to do with how i'm getting the onclick to work and in the class that it doesnt work(1 st one) i am using the xml file to do the onClick but the class it does work(2nd one) i am creating the onclick method within the class itself

Comment: The code has basic issues, a clean will not fix it by itself.